# How to add more than one 'CRUD' column to jquery datatables serverside rendering?

Tags: mvc.jquery.datatables

I have got the server side jquery datatables pagination working in an MVC example. The vanilla example displayed the grid without additional columns/links for edit/details/delete.

I followed the following example below and successfully got an edit button to appear and have it navigate successfully to the MVC edit view:

```html
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tblrtr')) {
            $('#tblrtr').dataTable().fnDestroy();
            $('#tblrtr').dataTable().empty();

        }

        var complete = $('#tblrtr').DataTable(
            {
                "serverSide": true,
                "destroy": true,
                "processing": true,
                "ajax":
                    {
                        url: "/ReportsToRecords/RTRList",
                        method: "POST"
                    },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "reportingId" },
                    { "data": "title" },
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "reportsToId" },
                    { "data": "employeeId" },

                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "data": "id",
                        "searchable": false,
                        "sortable": false,
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            @*return '<a href="@Url.Action("Edit","ReportsToRecords")?id=' + data + '" class="editRTR">Edit</a>'; }*@
                            return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/ReportsToRecords/Edit/' + full.id + '">Edit</a>'; }
                    }



                ]
            }

        );

        /// Following code is for filter input to apply filter only on Enter
        var itm = $("#tblrtr_filter input")

        itm.unbind();
        itm.keyup(function (e) {
            //enter or tab
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                complete.search(this.value).draw();
            }
        });


    });
</script>
```

I now wanted to add the details and delete navigational buttons to the respective mvc views. But if I simply replicate the code after the data columns, and make appropriate changes  to the return line in that code, the rendering of the grid ceases to work.

It doesnt seem to like more than one button column defined. Does anyone know the correct syntax to have the details and delete buttons also added? I know there seems to be a editable datatables with pop up screen to do this, but I am trying to use existing mvc views.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

found out I had to change it to the following:

```html
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {  
                            return '<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "ReportsToRecords")?id=' + data + '" class="editReportsToRecords">Edit</a> | <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "ReportsToRecords")?id=' + data + '" class="detailsReportsToRecords">Details</a> | <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "ReportsToRecords")?id=' + data + '" class="deleteReportsToRecords">Delete</a>';  }
```